# Heroku app uploads only once w/ AWS S3 security credentials

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip, aws-sdk

Heroku app gives a error message to have a look at the logs and `heroku logs --tail` shows 401 error or writes simply "idle" when uploading a file to amazon S3. Once I have seen SQL statement for inserting file into MariaDB. What's this all about?

I changed the AWS S3 security credentials, both in AWS console and in my heroku environment. Then the upload works for one single time.

Expected: AWS S3 upload works permanently.

Actual: file gets uploaded only once.

```
leder@DESKTOP-M6L5EDG:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
leder@DESKTOP-M6L5EDG:~$ rails -v
Rails 5.1.2
leder@DESKTOP-M6L5EDG:~$
```

Comment: I suspect paperclip to be unstable, still. I will try to update my installation. But I am not sure if `bundle update` is sufficient.

Comment: `bundle update paperclip` should do the trick...